# Opera error page not reloading

Tags: javascript, html, opera

I've got an error in opera that is `window.location.reload()` not working any solutions?

EDIT

```
$(".twitter").live("click",function(){
    $.oauthpopup({
        path: 'twitter.php',
        callback: function(){
            alert("successfully Tweetted");
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Works for me on that (SO) site, when I run via Dragonfly. Have you tried running it via Dragonfly console? BTW. Some code would be appreciated ;)

Comment: the obvious: is it triggering an error? and it's not an iframe, right?

Comment: I downloaded oauthpopup from http://zuzara.com/blog/2010/05/15/jquery-plugin-for-twitter-oauth-via-popup-window-facebook-style/, added your code above. And now, when I click button, I get an window with "site not found" - which is obvious, because I don't have that script. But, when I close that popup I get `successfully Tweetted` alert and page is reloading on Opera 11.01.

Comment: which version of Opera are you using? Is there a web page somewhere with your script? Any messages in the error console?

Comment: @Harish have you tried with Opera 11. Does it exhibit the same behavior than Opera 10. I checked for window.location.reload() is well implemented. Could you also give the error message you get?

Comment: Is the document which you try to reload generated by document.write()? That's about the only situation I can think of where reload() would behave in an unexpected way.

Comment: Why don't you try `window.location = "Your Path Here";`, this will be easy I think so.

Comment: @Harish do you still have the issue